# wordpress based website - redirection to https + www working fine except in IE

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internet-explorer, redirect

I am currently trying to write redirect rules for my website but I am afraid I got stuck. I was wondering if anyone experienced a similar issue before and maybe would a a quick fix for me.

I am trying to redirect my user from:

```
domain
www.domain
http://domain
https://domain
http://www.domain
```

to a single

```
https://www.domain website.
```

So basically I want to force https connections and add the www in each case.

I am using the code below in the .htaccess file, and it seems to be working fine in chrome and firefox, but IE(11)  does not seem to process it.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there any inherent reason why IE cannot process it? If you have any tips or suggestion, I am all ears :)

Thanks in advance.